# What's the reward of "Find the Old Montilyet Family Crest"?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

After completing this quest on the war table, nothing happened. I talked to Josephine, but no new chat option or any reaction arose about it. Am I missing something here?

Is there any quest or event after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... I found the answer from journey log. This unlocks an item (**Montilyet Family Crest**) sold by **Barnabus** in **Val Royeaux**.

After purchased it, you can proceed the quest **Heraldry from a Herald**.

Answer (score -1):

This allows you to use the heraldry as decoration when the inquisitor acquires property.